Implementing Search_after and PIT For Elastic Search for Deep Pagination
So, I am currently working on a project where there are 1 million+ documents to be shown (certificates/marriage/death/homes/etc.) And they all need to be displayed (Yes I know, doesn't sound good but it has too). I'm currently using Elastic Search, Python, Flask, and Docker in my project. And I have a function called browse all with some of the search_after and PIT Included, but I keep getting different errors such as Jinja Undefined, Type Error, Unresolved, etc. I also get errors where the image does not show. I read the docs on Elastic Search and tried my best with what I have, but to no avail. So I do need help. Attached is my code below, for the browse all.
@blueprint.route("/browse-all", methods=["GET"])
def browse_all():
    """
    This view function handles GET requests for the Browse All page.
    A query is made for the initial page of certificates shown.

    :return: Template for the browse all page and a list of certificates to display.
             Redirect to public.view_certificate if only one certificate is returned.
    """
    # Get default year range/values
    try:
        cached_year_range = get_year_range()
        if cached_year_range and cached_year_range.year_min and cached_year_range.year_max:
            default_year_range_value = f"{cached_year_range.year_min} - {cached_year_range.year_max}"
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid year range")
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(f"Error getting year range: {str(e)}")
        default_year_range_value = "1855 - 1949"  # Fallback range

    form = BrowseAllForm()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    page_size = 50

    # Set up variables for search
    q_list = []

    for key, value in request.args.items():
        if key != 'page' and value:
            if key == "year_range":
                year_range = [int(year) for year in value.split() if year.isdigit()]
                if len(year_range) == 2:
                    q_list.append(Q("range", year={"gte": year_range[0], "lte": year_range[1]}))
            elif key in ["first_name", "last_name"]:
                q_list.append(Q("multi_match", query=value.capitalize(), fields=[key, f"spouse_{key}"]))
            elif key == "certificate_type" and value == "marriage":
                q_list.append(Q("terms", cert_type=[certificate_types.MARRIAGE, certificate_types.MARRIAGE_LICENSE]))
            else:
                q_list.append(Q("match", **{key: value}))

    q = Q("bool", must=q_list) if q_list else Q("match_all")

    # Define the sort order
    sort_order = [{"_doc": "asc"}]

    # Create a new PIT for each request
    pit = es.open_point_in_time(index="certificates", keep_alive="1m")
    pit_id = pit['id']

    # Get search_after from request arguments
    search_after = request.args.get('search_after')
    if search_after:
        search_after = search_after.split(',')

    # Construct the search body
    body = {
        "size": page_size,
        "query": q.to_dict(),
        "sort": sort_order,
        "pit": {
            "id": pit_id,
            "keep_alive": "1m"
        }
    }

    if search_after and page > 1:
        body["search_after"] = search_after

    # Perform the search
    try:
        response = es.search(body=body)
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(f"Elasticsearch error: {str(e)}")
        return render_template("public/error.html", error_message="An error occurred while searching. Please try again.")

    # Get the total count
    count = response["hits"]["total"]["value"]

    # If only one certificate is returned, go directly to the view certificate page
    if count == 1:
        es.close_point_in_time(id=pit_id)
        return redirect(url_for("public.view_certificate", certificate_id=response["hits"]["hits"][0]["_id"]))

    # Process hits to include image URLs
    processed_hits = []
    for hit in response['hits']['hits']:
        processed_hit = hit['_source']
        processed_hit['_id'] = hit['_id']
        if 'image_url' not in processed_hit:
            processed_hit['image_url'] = url_for('static', filename='images/placeholder.png')
        processed_hits.append(processed_hit)

    # Set form data from previous form submissions
    for field in form:
        if field.name in request.args:
            field.data = request.args[field.name]

    # Simplified remove_filters logic
    remove_filters = {}
    for key, value in request.args.items():
        if key not in ['page', 'search_after'] and value:
            if not (key == "year_range" and value == default_year_range_value):
                label = value
                if key == "certificate_type":
                    label = certificate_types.CERTIFICATE_TYPE_VALUES.get(value, value)
                elif key == "county":
                    label = counties.COUNTY_VALUES.get(value, value)
                
                args_without_filter = request.args.copy()
                args_without_filter.pop(key)
                new_url = url_for('public.browse_all', **args_without_filter)
                remove_filters[key] = (label, new_url)

    # Define pagination
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=count, per_page=page_size, css_framework="bootstrap4")
    
    next_page = page + 1 if len(response['hits']['hits']) == page_size else None

    # Prepare next_args for the next page URL
    next_args = request.args.copy()
    if next_page:
        next_args['page'] = next_page
        if response['hits']['hits']:
            next_args['search_after'] = ','.join(map(str, response['hits']['hits'][-1]['sort']))
    else:
        next_args.pop('page', None)
        next_args.pop('search_after', None)

    # Close the PIT
    es.close_point_in_time(id=pit_id)

    return render_template(
        "public/browse_all.html",
        form=form,
        certificates=processed_hits,
        pagination=pagination,
        remove_filters=remove_filters,
        num_results=count,
        next_page=next_page,
        next_args=next_args,
        certificate_types=certificate_types,
        counties=counties,
        min=min,
        default_year_range_value=default_year_range_value
    )

I tried search_after just by itself but then we will be upgrading to ElasticSearch 8 soon, and according to the docs, search_after will need PIT so I implemented both. Essentially, what I need is for the user to be able to go to page 201, 202, 203, etc etc. Until there is nothing else to be shown.
